# Log Custom SQL Results During Maintenance Plan

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows, maintenance

I would like the last step of my Maintenance Plan to execute a simple custom SQL script (`SELECT * FROM <SomeTable> WHERE <Condition>`), and save the results to a file (Text, CSV, etc).

Is this possible? The closest thing I've found is doing this in a `.bat` file that is executed by Windows, but that seems a little cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mixture of `xp_cmdshell` and `bcp`:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 
    'bcp "SELECT * FROM YourTable ...." queryout Log.txt -c -T'
```

The above extended stored procedure bcp call assumes a few things, such as a trusted connection.  But utilize the [BOL Reference for BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) to fine tune your call.